# Loading a zone without A entries

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone

I's like to load a zone which has a NS specified by no A. It's going to be used for dynammic updates (basic zone has to exist before the updates are done). This used to work with bind version 9.3.4, but after migrating to 9.7.3, I get for example:

```
zone localhost/IN: NS 'localhost' has no address records (A or AAAA)
zone localhost/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

Since the zone is going to be updated later on, I don't care about the missing entries. Is there some way to turn off this check and bring back the previous behaviour?

The example zone I'm testing is:

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 86400
localhost IN SOA localhost. root.localhost. (
16 ;
28800 ;
7200 ;
604800 ;
86400 ;
)
    NS localhost.
$ORIGIN localhost.
```

I know I can easily add the `A` record, but since those files are autogenerated in my case, I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: Duplicate of ["Yet another DNS question - No A or AAAA record for NS"](http://serverfault.com/questions/116882/).

Comment: @JdeBP Not really - I do know why it happens. I want to know how to ignore that check in my specific scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an A record for localhost, otherwise how would you resolve what `NS localhost.` is? Without an at least an A record for that, this zone is unusable. Bascially, you need to be able to resolve the nameserver record, autogenerated or not.

Comment: I know it's needed in practice, but that record will be added dynamically after the server is started. I'd like to load this zone even if it doesn't make much sense at the start.